# Is it possible to add custom preview images in og tags for different pages of a website?

Tags: php, yii2, facebook-opengraph

I am trying to add og tag on each view page of my website. But it is only rendering the og tag of the layout page(index page).

Is it possible to add different title/images in views for every page?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Yes, of course it is. But we can’t possible tell you what you might have done wrong, as long as you give us almost zero actually useful info.

Comment: Please add the code you already tried and describe how it doesnt work for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. From inside view you can this for example:

```
$this->registerMetaTag([
    'property' => 'og:image',
    'content' => 'path/to/file'
]);
```

where `$this` is `View` object you've got access to from view.

Meta property will be added automatically in your layout if you've got there `<?php $this->head() ?>`